# proof that the vectors are linearly dependent

Tags: linear-algebra

> $v_1,v_2,w \in R^n$
>
> $w $ is in the span {$v_1,v_2$}
>
> Show that the vectors {$v_1,v_2,w$} are linear dependent.

My first approach was:
$w=a*v_1+b*v_2$

and because $w$ is in the span of $v_1, v_2$, there should also scalar values $x,y,z$
which result in the zero element.

$0=x*v_1+y*v_2+z*w$

instead of w, I think I could write

$0=x*v_1+y*v_2+(a*v_1+b*v_2)$
but how to proof that they result in the zero element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't quite the right approach.  Instead, consider
$$
w = av_1 + bv_2
$$
Take $w$ over to the other side to get
$$
(-1)w + (a)v_1 + (b)v_2 = 0
$$
What does this show?

Comment: it shows, that they are linearly dependent. Because there are scalar values, which result in 0, when multiplied with the vectors.

Comment: @SuperNova Indeed!!

Comment: but according to this equation the value for w is (-1). This is only one case, but isn't there any way to proof this in general?

Comment: Because a linear combinaison of those vectors with at least on non-zero coefficient gives $0$. It is general because of the $a$ and $b$. But you only need one coefficient to be non-zero so you don't care about those.

Comment: We have already proved it in general.  All you have to do to show $w, v_1, v_2$ are linearly dependent is show that *some* coefficients make them sum to zero.  In this case we have used the coefficients $-1, a, b$, and thus they are linearly dependent.

Comment: Thanks, so the key is that there is an actual value (-1), instead of a variable?

Comment: @SuperNova It doesn't matter what it is, "actual value" or "variable".  As long as you can write down some numbers such that $\_\_\_ w + \_\_\_ v_1 + \_\_\_ v_2 = 0$, then you are done.  But you have to be able to prove that your numbers work.

Answer (score 0):

You want to prove that there are $(x,y,z)\not=(0,0,0)$ so that $xv_1+yv_2+zw=0$.

Since $w=av_1+bv_2$, you get $xv_1+yv_2+z(av_1+bv_2)=0$.

Using associativity, commutativity and distributivity, you get $(x+za)v_1+(y+zb)v_2=0$.

And from that, you should be able to get what you want.